Different IP address when using a web application
My PC is in a domain and has a unique IP address 10.10.40.125. I print through a web application. This application reads from a database table the mappings between PCs and printer IP.
When mapped with this IP, which I get when I run ipconfig it does not print, yet after weeks of debugging using developer options, I found that it should be 192.168.4.25 and when I replaced it in the table, it worked on testing, when connected to live, I also had to use another IP 192.168.174.24. What are these other IPs are there anymore and how do I get them? ipconfig/all is not returning them.

How did you find those two addresses? Altogether I'd say this is impossible to answer from outside – can provide several guesses, but only your company's network admins would know for sure.

By chance, when I pressed Print, I went to network tab in dev options and I pressed response, I found in the response. I cannot recreate it anymore.

@grawity Please do, anything will help.

The app runs on the webserver., something is doing NAT to your IP.


What are these other IPs

Impossible to know for sure, but very likely to be either a) the IP address of a reverse proxy or load balancer that is relaying your requests, or b) the IP address of a NAT gateway that performs source address translation (for some weird reason).
In the first case, it would be the load balancer that's making the real connection to the web app server, so that's what the app would see. (Most load balancers have a special protocol to send the real address to the backend but it needs to be specifically enabled.)
The second case would be very much like how ipconfig doesn't return your public IP address either (because it's the router's address, not yours).

and how do I get them?

The only reliable method is to have the webapp show them to you. Otherwise it's almost impossible to know where some kind of NAT or proxying is done.
Beware that there likely won't be a 1:1 correspondence between your real address and the one seen by the app. It might even be that the app sees all users – or everyone from the same subnet – as the same IP address.
